# Pandas: Join Date and Time into one datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with 13 columns, where two columns are "Date" and "Time".

I would like to 
1) join "Date" and "Time" and
2) format the result correctly (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS)

```
        Date    Time
0   2012-09-27  00:40:20
1   2012-09-27  07:24:37
2   2012-09-27  07:25:08
3   2012-09-27  07:43:48
4   2012-09-27  07:44:27
5   2012-09-27  07:55:16
6   2012-09-27  08:04:19
7   2012-09-27  08:08:21
8   2012-09-27  08:09:08
9   2012-09-27  08:15:30
10  2012-09-27  08:15:35
```

So I try:

```
>type(df["Date"])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

And I think to myself "Why not convert them both in to string representations and manipulate them that way?"

```
>g = df["Time"].astype(str)
>type(g)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

"What?! It's still a Series?!"

So I try to be creative:

```
>f = df["Date"].astype(str) + " " + df["Time"].astype(str)
>f
0     2012-09-27 00:40:20
1     2012-09-27 07:24:37
2     2012-09-27 07:25:08
3     2012-09-27 07:43:48
```

"Hey! That works! No let's just get the format right (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS)"

```
>#dt.strptime(f, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

"Still a Series...hmmm....Obviously it won't let itself be converted. Let's try something else"

```
>f = p.concat([df["Date"], df["Time"]], axis=1)
>f
        Date    Time
0   2012-09-27  00:40:20
1   2012-09-27  07:24:37
2   2012-09-27  07:25:08
```

"Nice! But.... Isn't this TWO columns still...?"

```
>f.shape
(100,2)
```

"Right...back to square one...."

I'm out of ideas....

Anyone?

Comment: Strange that this could not be solved more effectively. But thanks anyway for the answers, all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.astype(str)` works on the elements of Series, not the Series itself, so of course `type(df["Time"].astype(str)) == pd.Series`. This seems to be the source of much of your confusion, you're acting on the Series, *not* its elements.

A solution (there maybe an easier way) is to just loop over the series:

```
dts = [datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S') 
       for elem in df['Date'] + df['Time']]

fmted = [elem.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') for elem in dts]

df.insert(0, 'DateTime', fmted)
```

Comment: I used your implementation and now it works. Thanks.
Your implementation also catered for the formatting I was after.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need join columns with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Date']))
<class 'str'>
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Time']))
<class 'str'>

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + " " + df['Time'])
```

If there is datetime with `string`s:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Date']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Time']))
<class 'str'>

df['datetime'] = df['Date']  + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

If there is datetime with `time`s:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Date']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Time']))
<class 'datetime.time'>

df['datetime'] = df['Date']  + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
```

And if there are dates with times:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Date']))
<class 'datetime.date'>

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Time']))
<class 'datetime.time'>

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype(str) + " " + df["Time"].astype(str))
```

---

```
print (df)
          Date      Time            datetime
0   2012-09-27  00:40:20 2012-09-27 00:40:20
1   2012-09-27  07:24:37 2012-09-27 07:24:37
2   2012-09-27  07:25:08 2012-09-27 07:25:08
3   2012-09-27  07:43:48 2012-09-27 07:43:48
4   2012-09-27  07:44:27 2012-09-27 07:44:27
5   2012-09-27  07:55:16 2012-09-27 07:55:16
6   2012-09-27  08:04:19 2012-09-27 08:04:19
7   2012-09-27  08:08:21 2012-09-27 08:08:21
8   2012-09-27  08:09:08 2012-09-27 08:09:08
9   2012-09-27  08:15:30 2012-09-27 08:15:30
10  2012-09-27  08:15:35 2012-09-27 08:15:35
```

Comment: So the only way to joint `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` is by converting to strings? That's seriously slow.

Answer (score 2):

the columns can be joined and assigned to a new or existing column in the dataframe:

```
df['datetime'] = df['dates'] + " " + df['time']
```

outputs example:

```
        dates      time             datetime
0  2012-09-27  00:40:20  2012-09-27 00:40:20
1  2012-09-27  07:24:37  2012-09-27 07:24:37
2  2012-09-27  07:25:08  2012-09-27 07:25:08
```